# Android APK not installing in device

Tags: android, android-build, failed-installation, android-install-apk

I have created Same project as two WorkSpace in my system .
  ex:  AppSampleHindi and AppSampleEnglish,

1. once i run the app i am getting error so how to solve this error.
2. and instant run option is not there in my android studio

```js
$ adb install-multiple -r -t /Users/Name/Desktop/AppName/app/build/intermediates/resources/instant-run/debug/resources-debug.apk 
Error while installing apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the two projects have different package names, otherwise installation will fail.
Open your **AndroidManifest.xml** file and look for "package" property.

Comment: can i put different package name ..? see in my device i dont install both apk , but AppSampleHindi workspace apk will install succesfully , but AppSampleEnglish workspace is only not installing

Comment: probably AppSampleEnglish has the same package name of AppSampleHindi

Comment: hello please understand my question.....both are same package only, i am installing both application in my device,

Comment: ******sorry i am not installing both app in my device

Comment: Are you sure you have developer options enabled and install via usb option checked in your phone settings?